# Server access error while running sbt assembly

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

```
sparkuser@spark:~$ sbt assembly/ Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
-javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar  Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.9 ...

:: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9

    ==== local: tried

      /home/sparkuser/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9!sbt.jar:

      /home/sparkuser/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/jars/sbt.jar

    ==== jcenter: tried

      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9!sbt.jar:

      https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9!sbt.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.9: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS     Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.jar

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/ivys/ivy.xml

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9/sbt-0.13.9.jar
```

Comment: in your projects folder, what sbt version did you specify in build.properties?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

it helped me.

Comment: And for Windows users ?

Comment: @Itération122442 First step should be like this: remove windows and install gnu/linux.